# Modifying PreSaveAction Function

Tags: javascript, custom-form

I currently have a PreSaveAction function that I was given. It currently looks at the people picker field (Reviewer 2) to make sure it is filled before allowing the form to be saved. Is there a way to change it to look at the choice field (Rev2 Required) instead?
Here's my script:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function PreSaveAction(){
    //these look for the display name values in the associated people pickers
    var rev2 = $("input[Title='Reviewer 2']").attr("aria-label");

    if(rev2){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        alert("You must select a person as Reviewer 2. Please refer to the Approval and Payment of Invoices policy for guidelines.");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is not a SharePoint question but a jQuery lesson 1 question  https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Can you check this for me? Something doesn't seem right. 

`<script type="text/javascript"> function PreSaveAction(){ //these look for the display name values in the choice field var choiceFieldValue = $("select[title$='ChoiceFieldName']").val(); if(choiceFieldValue){ return true; } else{ alert("Does this invoice require a second reviewer? If so, please refer to the Approval and Payment of Invoices policy for guidelines."); return false; } } </script>`

Comment: No, code in comments is unreadable. As I said your issue is most likely jQuery selectors you don't master.. Open F12 Console (learn to use the console instead of alert) and test your selectors there first. You can't run when you never learned to walk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to use `Select` for Choice field.

```
var choiceFieldValue =  $("select[title$='ChoiceFieldName']").val();
```

Then check the variable according to your requirement.